# I am having trouble with DataTable not working (ajax doesn't fire off)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am following this tutorial:

https://gist.github.com/ChinhP/9b4dc1df1b12637b99a420aa268ae32b

I have a problem where the ajax won't fire. Any suggestions?

I am trying to get a table with a previous, next, first and last button.

```
var data = { "number": 0, "currentPosition": 1 };
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

//var output = "";

/*$.ajax('/Companies/GetData', {
datatype: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
type: 'post',
data: JSON.stringify({ dataTableParameters: data }),
success: function (response) {
    output = response;
}
});*/

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#CompanyTable').dataTable(
    {
        "sPaginationType": "full",
        processing: true,
        bserverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            "url": "../Companies/GetData",
            "type": "POST",
            "contentType": "application/json",
            data: function (d) {
                console.log('enter');
                // note: d is created by datatable, the structure of d is 
the same with DataTableParameters model above
                console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
                return JSON.stringify(d);
            },
            success: function (response)
            {
                console.log(response)
            }
        }

    });
 });
```

Comment: Hello... You really need to post the code you've written, highlight the bit that's not working and say what you've attempted in order to resolve the issue.

Comment: I believe `bserverSide` should be `serverSide`. You appear to be mixing the old Hungarian notation (which should be `bServerSide`) and newer camelCase notion for properties.

Comment: Can you explain the "AJAX won't fire" condition? Which version of `DataTable` plugin used & what you're expect?

Comment: I am trying to follow this example: "https://gist.github.com/ChinhP/9b4dc1df1b12637b99a420aa268ae32b". I have a ajax which fires on it own. However, the ajax won't fire when it is included in a data table. It doesn't hit my breakpoint in VS2017. I am using version 1.10.15 of datatable.